# Gradle error after updating to implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.2' and classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:3.3.0'

Tags: java, android, gradle, google-play-services

I updated com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads to 15.0.2 and classpath com.google.gms:google-services: to 3.3.0 then i got this error;

**Could not GET 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds/com/google/android/gms/play-services-ads/15.0.2/play-services-ads-15.0.2.pom'. Received status code 403 from server: Forbidden
Enable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project**

I enabled gradle offline but i get this error:

**No cached version of com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.2 available for offline mode.
Disable Gradle 'offline mode' and sync project**

Please help.

```
allprojects {
repositories {
    google()
    jcenter()
    maven { url "https://s3.amazonaws.com/moat-sdk-builds" }
}
```

}

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think version 15.0.2 of google play ads has been released out yet. Use the following:

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:15.0.1'
```

You can find latest releases of Google's libraries [here.](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup#add_google_play_services_to_your_project)

Also note that Firebase(Google) has started versioning libraries separately. You can find more details by following this link: https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/android

Comment: thank you very much. i was wrong, 15.0.2 is for firebase-core

Comment: Glad I could help. :)